# AndroidVideoCache video cache without playing Video View

Tags: android, caching, video

AndroidVideoCache video cache without playing Video View. I need to implement it before the default player activity and cache video.
I have tried the following link : https://github.com/danikula/AndroidVideoCache/issues/59
But it is not working.

Comment: have you solved this because I am havinf same issue?